# Get data in one column

Tags: php, html, mysql, excel

I'm now trying to export data from my database to an excel file. However, when I open the excel file the data is all in one column. I would like get everything from one row in the MySql database in one Column. Example all the usernames should be in one column, all the firstnames in one column and so one

Php code:

```
<?php


//include database configuration file
include ('connection.php');

//get records from database
$sql = ("SELECT * FROM employee ORDER BY username DESC");

if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){ 
    $delimiter = ",";
    $filename = "members_" . date('Y-m-d') . ".csv";

    //create a file pointer
    $f = fopen('php://memory', 'w');

    //set column headers
    $field1 = "username"; 
    $field2 = "firstname"; 
    $field3 = "lastname"; 
    $field4 = "phonenumber"; 
    $field5 = "password"; 
    $fields = array($field1 . $field2 . $field3 . $field4 . $field5); 
    fputcsv($f, $fields, $delimiter);

    //output each row of the data, format line as csv and write to file pointer
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 

        $lineData = array($row['username'], $row['firstname'], $row['lastname'], $row['phonenumber'], $row['password']);
        fputcsv($f, $lineData, $delimiter);
    }

    //move back to beginning of file
    fseek($f, 0);

    //set headers to download file rather than displayed
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '";');

    //output all remaining data on a file pointer
    fpassthru($f);
}
}
exit;


?>
```

My html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            Members list
            <a href="exportData.php" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Export Members</a>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Name</th>
                      <th>Email</th>
                      <th>Phone</th>
                      <th>Created</th>
                      <th>Status</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php
                    //include database configuration file
                    include 'connection.php';

                    //get records from database
                    $sql = ("SELECT * FROM employee ORDER BY username DESC");
                    if($sql->num_rows > 0){ 
                            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){  ?>                
                    <tr>
                      <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row['phone']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row['created']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo ($row['status'] == '1')?'Active':'Inactive'; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php } }else{ ?>
                    <tr><td colspan="5">No member(s) found.....</td></tr>
                    <?php } ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I have been googling for the past 2 hours and can not find the solution. Do you know some tools or language or the way to solve this ?

BR

Comment: `$fields = array($field1 . $field2 . $field3 . $field4 . $field5);` is concatenation of `fields`-variables. Replace `.` with `,`.

Comment: How are your PHP and HTML related? You also never execute your SQL query in the HTML part. That code would fail on many levels.

Answer (score 1):

Display the data in a common HTML table then convert & download the excel file

```js
var xport = {
  _fallbacktoCSV: true,  
  toXLS: function(tableId, filename) {   
    this._filename = (typeof filename == 'undefined') ? tableId : filename;
    
    //var ieVersion = this._getMsieVersion();
    //Fallback to CSV for IE & Edge
    if ((this._getMsieVersion() || this._isFirefox()) && this._fallbacktoCSV) {
      return this.toCSV(tableId);
    } else if (this._getMsieVersion() || this._isFirefox()) {
      alert("Not supported browser");
    }

    //Other Browser can download xls
    var htmltable = document.getElementById(tableId);
    var html = htmltable.outerHTML;

    this._downloadAnchor("data:application/vnd.ms-excel" + encodeURIComponent(html), 'xls'); 
  },
  toCSV: function(tableId, filename) {
    this._filename = (typeof filename === 'undefined') ? tableId : filename;
    // Generate our CSV string from out HTML Table
    var csv = this._tableToCSV(document.getElementById(tableId));
    // Create a CSV Blob
    var blob = new Blob([csv], { type: "text/csv" });

    // Determine which approach to take for the download
    if (navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
      // Works for Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge
      navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, this._filename + ".csv");
    } else {      
      this._downloadAnchor(URL.createObjectURL(blob), 'csv');      
    }
  },
  _getMsieVersion: function() {
    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;

    var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");
    if (msie > 0) {
      // IE 10 or older => return version number
      return parseInt(ua.substring(msie + 5, ua.indexOf(".", msie)), 10);
    }

    var trident = ua.indexOf("Trident/");
    if (trident > 0) {
      // IE 11 => return version number
      var rv = ua.indexOf("rv:");
      return parseInt(ua.substring(rv + 3, ua.indexOf(".", rv)), 10);
    }

    var edge = ua.indexOf("Edge/");
    if (edge > 0) {
      // Edge (IE 12+) => return version number
      return parseInt(ua.substring(edge + 5, ua.indexOf(".", edge)), 10);
    }

    // other browser
    return false;
  },
  _isFirefox: function(){
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") > 0) {
      return 1;
    }
    
    return 0;
  },
  _downloadAnchor: function(content, ext) {
      var anchor = document.createElement("a");
      anchor.style = "display:none !important";
      anchor.id = "downloadanchor";
      document.body.appendChild(anchor);

      // If the [download] attribute is supported, try to use it
      
      if ("download" in anchor) {
        anchor.download = this._filename + "." + ext;
      }
      anchor.href = content;
      anchor.click();
      anchor.remove();
  },
  _tableToCSV: function(table) {
    // We'll be co-opting `slice` to create arrays
    var slice = Array.prototype.slice;

    return slice
      .call(table.rows)
      .map(function(row) {
        return slice
          .call(row.cells)
          .map(function(cell) {
            return '"t"'.replace("t", cell.textContent);
          })
          .join(",");
      })
      .join("\r\n");
  }
};
```

```html
<h1>Html table to excel or csv <small style="font-size:17px">---With export for IE and Edge</small></h1>

<p> Test1: <button id="btnExport" onclick="javascript:xport.toXLS('testTable');"> Export to XLS</button> <em>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Export the table to XLS with CSV fallback for IE & Edge</em>
  </p>

<p>Test 2: <button id="btnExport" onclick="javascript:xport.toCSV('testTable');"> Export to CSV</button> <em>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Export the table to CSV for all browsers</em>
  </p>

<p> Test3: <button id="btnExport" onclick="javascript:xport.toXLS('testTable', 'outputdata');"> Export to XLS</button> <em>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Export the table to XLS with custom filename</em>
  </p>
<br />

<table id="testTable" summary="Code page support in different versions of MS Windows." rules="groups" frame="hsides" border="2" class="table table-striped">
  <caption>CODE-PAGE SUPPORT IN MICROSOFT WINDOWS</caption>
  <colgroup align="center"></colgroup>
  <colgroup align="left"></colgroup>
  <colgroup span="2" align="center"></colgroup>
  <colgroup span="3" align="center"></colgroup>
  <thead valign="top">
    <tr>
      <th>Code-Page<br>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>ACP</th>
      <th>OEMCP</th>
      <th>Windows<br>NT 3.1</th>
      <th>Windows<br>NT 3.51</th>
      <th>Windows<br>95</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1200</td>
      <td style="background-color: #00f; color: #fff">Windows 3.11</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>*</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1250</td>
      <td style="font-weight: bold">Windows 3.1 Eastern European</td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>X</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1251</td>
      <td>Windows 3.1 Cyrillic</td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>X</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1252</td>
      <td>Windows 3.1 US (ANSI)</td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>X</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1253</td>
      <td>Windows 3.1 Greek</td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>X</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1254</td>
      <td>Windows 3.1 Turkish</td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>X</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1255</td>
      <td>Hebrew</td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>X</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1256</td>
      <td>Arabic</td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>X</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1257</td>
      <td>Baltic</td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>X</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1361</td>
      <td>Korean (Johab)</td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>**</td>
      <td>X</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>437</td>
      <td>MS-DOS United States</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>X</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>708</td>
      <td>Arabic (ASMO 708)</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>X</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>709</td>
      <td>Arabic (ASMO 449+, BCON V4)</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>X</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>710</td>
      <td>Arabic (Transparent Arabic)</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>X</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>720</td>
      <td>Arabic (Transparent ASMO)</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>X</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you open the file in Excel, you need to transform it to columns.

Under the "Data" (either the menu option or the tab), select "Data to Columns".  Choose the appropriate format for the data.  Quite possibly, this is delimited with a comma.

Alternatively, create the file using a tab separator, which is the default field separator in Excel.